# Admin page Problem after upgrade from magento 2.3.5-p1 to magento 2.3.5-p2

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, adminform, design, magento2.3.5

After upgrade from magento 2.3.5-p1 to magento 2.3.5-p2
when I try to use the admin panel almost all menu button not responding.
only the Dashboard button working.
I dont get any error in logs.
I also tried to compile, deploy and clean cache.

```
www.ttu.co.il/:14 Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src getfirebug.com *.googleapis.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.
www.ttu.co.il/:1 Refused to load the script 'https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/7089c43e/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src assets.adobedtm.com geostag.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafstag.cardinalcommerce.com geoapi.cardinalcommerce.com 1eafapi.cardinalcommerce.com songbird.cardinalcommerce.com includestest.ccdc02.com www.googleadservices.com www.google-analytics.com secure.authorize.net test.authorize.net www.paypal.com www.sandbox.paypal.com www.paypalobjects.com t.paypal.com s.ytimg.com video.google.com vimeo.com www.vimeo.com js.authorize.net jstest.authorize.net js.braintreegateway.com cdn-scripts.signifyd.com www.youtube.com *.googleapis.com *.addthis.com *.moatads.com *.addthisedge.com *.facebook.com *.pinterest.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

[image: admin panel]

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Have you try by disabling the cdn?

Comment: no, 
cloudflare rocket loader was the problem, after disabled the admin panel working well.
thanks

Comment: I post answer, that will help please upvote and mark as solutin so it will help other in community as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the following way.

1. Disable the CDN, if you have setup and then check.
2. Disable the third party extension one by one which you install and then check.